# Java date does not parse day

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-8

I have a weird problem, when I try to parse this date: `Tue Nov 03 10:50:16 CET 2015` using the java SimpleDateFormat, it throws an exception because of the "Tue" in there.
My code is:

```
String date = "Tue Nov 03 10:50:16 CET 2015";
Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(date);
```

Which throws this exception: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Nov 03 10:50:16 CET 2015"`

I have tried debugging it, and this is what is boils down to:

```
String date = "Tue";
Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").parse(date);
```

Which throws the same type of exception. (I also tried it with a single 'E'). I think this is really strange, because the documentation tells me that this is how it should be used. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Solutions are more than welcome!
Thanks, Luca

Update: the point of the parsing is to parse `MANIFEST.getMainAttributes().getValue("Created-On");`

Comment: What is your locale? The textual day and month representation depend on that.

Comment: Try to pass in the "en-us" Locale to the constructor to lock down that part.

Comment: You can try @cheffe suggestion like this `SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH)`. By the way I've tested your code with your String and it works fine. Language in my system English

Comment: @cheffe Good point, my date and time format is set to Dutch, and you just fixed the problem :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to cheffe I figured out the solution:

```
Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
```

Which worked! :)